# jquery.tablesorter: checkbox in non-sortable column causes resort

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm having a problem with my table using tablesorter 2 where each cell in my first column has a checkbox (I'll be using it to delete multiple rows later), I've set `data-sorter="false" data-filter="false"` in the column `<th>` as in the docs, and that seem to be working fine... but when I click on the checkbox, the whole table updates and resorts.

I know it's resorting because I have a function in the second column to rewrite the index numbers starting at 1 going down that starts at the end of each sort.

Here's a working copy of my test code: https://jsfiddle.net/ok309fpx/

Same test code with more rows: https://jsfiddle.net/r8kr204b/

Try clicking the checkbox and you'll see that the whole table updates and resorts.

I've been working on this for hours, can't seem to figure out a way to stop that...

When the table is done it'll be filled with up to 1000 rows and at 150 rows it was already getting laggy (at least with the checkboxes).

Maybe the checkbox updating isn't the issue, maybe there's something else I'm missing, I'm a little stuck.

Anyone have any experience with this, any ideas?

Comment: I can't duplicate the resort mentioned in the demos that were provided.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, you don't need code to add a row index. It can be done with CSS - I've modified [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ok309fpx/1/) to show you how.

Comment: @Mottie I appreciate that, I had no idea CSS had that property.... and also great work with tablesorter. The fiddle's I provided both duplicate the resort. If you click on a checkbox, the numbers will then show, the index function is binded to `sortEnd` - is there any way to stop the table from resorting after updating input/select values in the table? Only when resorting via the top?

Comment: My issue is that the table becomes way to slow when it's constantly resorting the whole thing

Comment: Just like how you can change: `editable_autoResort    : false`